# geom_text not working when ggmap and geom_point used

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggmap

HI I am using ggmap and gg_point function to show the measured data in an estuary.

The code that I used is as follows:

> ```
>     library(ggmap)
> al1 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -87.525, lat = 30.35), zoom = 12, maptype = 'terrain')
>
> lon<- c(-87.604474,-87.55)
> lat<- c(30.362563,30.35)
> label <- c("A","B")
> df<-data.frame(lon,lat,label)
>
> p <- ggmap(al1)+geom_point(data=df,aes(x=lon,y=lat,shape=label,label=label),size=3)
> p <- p + xlab("Longitude")+ylab("Latitude")
> p <- p +geom_text(aes(label=label, size=3,vjust=0))
> p <- p + labs(title="Monitoring stations ")
> p
>
> ggsave("plot.pdf")
> ```

Here when I use geom_text then I get the following error, "Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:label".

I want to place the label next to the points in the plot. I would like to place both points and label and with some spacing so that it would be easier to read.

I looked at this post "[ggplot legend issue w/ geom_point and geom_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221168/ggplot-legend-issue-w-geom-point-and-geom-text)" and tried to fix my code as you can see above but I don't know why I am having this issue.

There is another post [How can I persuade ggplot2 geom_text to label a specified date in a time series plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578536/how-can-i-persuade-ggplot2-geom-text-to-label-a-specified-date-in-a-time-series) which talks the similar questions. Am I getting different results because I am using ggmap also ?

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you so much.

Jdbaba

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that you haven't specified the aesthetics in `geom_text` correctly:

```
geom_text(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = label), 
          size = 3, vjust = 0, hjust = -0.5)
```

You didn't tell `geom_text` to use the variables from the data frame `df`. If you don't do this, all aesthetics are inherited from the main call. Finally, when setting aesthetics to a single value, you don't do this inside of `aes()`, but outside.

I monkeyed with the `hjust` setting to get the labels to be visible.

Comment: Thanks joran, I just figured out that and was going to post that. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Jdbaba No problem. (I was wrong about unmapping `shape`, btw.)

Comment: I am just learning R and ggplot and am very excited with type of support you guys provide. Thanks @Joran and @ Josh O'Brien